# Does adb reboot recovery require unlock?

Tags: recovery-mode

I want to remove the LG G3 overshapening thing as instructed here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/orig-development/kernel-chupachups-kernel-t2943339

To do so I need to reboot in recovery mode.
I've connected my phone to usb and enabled usb debugging and authorized.
When I issue `adb devices` I can see my phone.
When then I issue `adb reboot recovery` the phone reboots, the image of the robot with the open hood and a red triangle appears... nothing else happens. Neither the power button works. All I can do is to remove the battery...
So I'm wondering do I first need to unlock the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing *is* the recovery.  You've successfully booted into it.  It displays that image when it hasn't been told by the main OS what it should do (e.g. something like a system upgrade).

However, it's the the *stock* recovery that comes with the device, which isn't really useful for much besides doing factory resets.  When someone tells you to "flash the zip in recovery", they're assuming that you've replaced the phone's stock recovery with a custom one such as [TWRP](https://twrp.me/) or [CWM](https://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager).  Installing one of those *does* require unlocking.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is normal.  You can list the different options in this mode by using the volume up and down buttons and the power button as a selection button.  To get out of this mode, you will need to do a hard-reset (hold down the power button for about 10 seconds).

I found a brief writeup that covers recovery mode options for the LG G3 
[here](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/use-recovery-mode-android/).

Comment: Thanks... but the thing is that when theis image appears (http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/use-recovery-mode-android/attachment/recovery_4/) nothing else is shown. No options and nothing happens whatever combination of keys I press. This is with the adb reboot recovery command...

Comment: Try rebooting into recovery without the ADB command (Power and Volume up, release power after reboot and continue to hold volume up until you see a unique screen).  Have you tried holding volume up/down for several seconds in the mode you are currently in?  Apparently there is a guide for this problem: https://fairphone.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201654943--Resting-Android-robot-No-Command-Black-screen-on-reboot

Comment: None of the mentioned methods / links work for me...